# Joining table with some priority wise or other possible ways to solve

Tags: mysql

I'm having two tables

Route_Table

```
Route_id From_id   To_id
       1 City1  City5
       2 City5  City1
       3 City5  City4
       4 City1  City3
```

Via_table Content

```
via_id, route_id,  City_id, Priority 
     1         1   city2    1
     2         1   city3    2
     3         1   city4    3
     4         2   city4    1
     5         2   city3    2
     6         2   city2    3
     7         4   city2    1
```

I'm having query to get the route for particular search
like city1_id to city3_id

```
select route_id from route_Table as a 
left_join via_Table as b on a.route_id=b.route_id 
left join via_Table as b1 on a.route_id=b1.route_id 
where (a.from_id=city1_id And a.to_id=city2_id)
or (a.from_id=city1_id And b.city_id=city2_id)
or (b.city_id=city1_id AND b1.city_id=city2_id) 
or (b.city_id=city1_id AND a.to_id=city2_id);
```

Here i get correct details for every query like am going city2 to city4 
getting route id

> 1,4

city1 to city5

> 1

but the problem is city2 to city4 is not necessary for

> 4

because it return path. how can rectify this problem 
I think problem will solve via route id or route_priority
but i don't any idea to rectify this problem
Thanks in advance...

Comment: why do you have duplicate via_ids in table route?

Comment: Note that 'from' is a reserved word in mysql - and did you put priority and city the wrong way around?

Comment: Do you want to solve traveling salesman problem in SQL?? :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: Yes, @GiorgiNakeuri if any change my mysql query to get correct route..

Comment: @Strawberry this just mock table my original table name changed

Comment: @JulioSoares there no dublicate id in via_id and there rotue_id is for which routes via id

Comment: @YuvarajJeganathan, seriously? It is hard problem for procedural language not to speak of SQL.

Comment: There is an error in the route_id values in the route_table. 2 occurs twice and 4 is not present, but is referenced in via table. I suppose it should read 1, 2, 3 and 4 in the route table?

Answer (score 1):

You should add a condition so that the `b` record is always before the `b1` record
in terms of priority. Also, to avoid duplicates, add a `distinct`:

```
select      distinct a.route_id
from        route_Table as a 
left join   via_Table as b 
        on  a.route_id = b.route_id 
left join   via_Table as b1
        on  a.route_id = b1.route_id
        and b.priority < b1.priority
where       (a.from_id = :city1_id and a.to_id    = :city2_id)
        or  (a.from_id = :city1_id and b.city_id  = :city2_id)
        or  (b.city_id = :city1_id and b1.city_id = :city2_id) 
        or  (b.city_id = :city1_id and a.to_id    = :city2_id);
```

Note that the query risks to become slow when there is a lot of data.
Things would simplify a lot, if you would also store the two end points of
a route in the `via_table` with priority 0 and 9999 respectively.
Without that, you could consider creating a view that simulates that:

```
create or replace view path as
select      route_id,
            city_id,
            priority
from        via_table
union
select      route_id,
            from_id,
            0
from        route_table
union
select      route_id,
            to_id,
            9999
from        route_table;
```

Then your query becomes:

```
select      b.route_id
from        path as b 
inner join  path as b1
        on  b.route_id = b1.route_id
        and b.priority < b1.priority
where       b.city_id  = :city1_id
        and b1.city_id = :city2_id;
```

I have applied that in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b142/1)